# Weird instance of NoMethodError undefined method for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, this is weird because this has worked for months, up until now.

The code in question is here...

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create                           #line 20
    User.transaction do              #line 21
        user = User.new(user_params) #line 22
        if user.save                 #line 23
...

private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Now all of this was working great for MONTHS. Then I decided I wanted to add a 'device_token' column to the User model. So...

```
My-MacBook-Pro:fffapi c$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20150329174839 AddDeviceTokenToUser: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :device_token, "char(64)", {:null=>true})
   -> 0.0015s
== 20150329174839 AddDeviceTokenToUser: migrated (0.0016s) ====================
```

Oops! Wait a second. This actually isn't the table I want it on at all. I want it on a different table. Let's get rid of that last change...

```
My-MacBook-Pro:fffapi c$ bundle exec rake db:rollback
== 20150329174839 AddDeviceTokenToUser: reverting =============================
-- remove_column(:users, :device_token, "char(64)", {:null=>true})
   -> 0.0023s
== 20150329174839 AddDeviceTokenToUser: reverted (0.0024s) ====================
```

Now, at this point I've restarted the server and rails console 3 times.

However, when I do the following POST to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/` with

```
{
  "user":
  {
    "name": "johnny",
    "email": "j@j.com",
    "password": "jjjjjj",
    "password_confirmation": "jjjjjj"
  }
}
```

I get the following error from the server...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `device_token' for #<User:0x007fc2e7d9c338>):
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

How can this be? What device_token is it even talking about, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Try full text search on your project directory for "device_token", it should reveal the problem, the method name is going from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea, why it didn't rollback.

But maybe you have some validations or callbacks that run on User creation?

Or just add some

```
Rails.logger.debug(user_params)
```

line to UsersController#create method to check that params really do not contain device_token field.

UPD: you can also grep your project to find this method call

```
grep -r 'device_token' ./app
```

Comment: It did rolled back, the method is missing, but it seems like it was called somewhere in the app.

Comment: I said the same to OP :)